# Convert(DATE, expr) to be implemented using CriteriaBuilder for Sql server

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I am using spring-data-jpa and implemented dynamic queries with `Specification` class.
Sql Server version is 2019 for db

There is one query where I need to truncate datetime(timestamp) to only date part (without time) and apply the where condition then.
The query is like:

```
select a from Table1 a where convert(DATE,date_col)>?
```

The problem is with the first parameter, i.e `DATE(this is actually a datatype and not a literal)`.

My code is running inside toPredicate method which is described as:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder)
```

I have tried using `criteriabuilder.function` method, but could not understand how to include the DATE(data type) in the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render this SQL you will have to register a custom `SQLFunction` to Hibernate that does exactly this.

```
public class TruncateDate implements SQLFunction {

    @Override
    public boolean hasArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
        return firstArgumentType;
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
        return "convert(DATE," + args.get(0) + ")";
    }
}
```

You will have to register the function within the Dialect.

So if the Dialect is being extended as indicated, this would be done with something like:

```
this.registerFunction("trunc_date", new TruncateDate());
```

Then you can use it like this: `criteriaBuilder.function('trunc_date', root.get("dateAttribute"))`